# Ubuntu 14.04 incomplete update

Tags: 14.04

I was updating from 13.10 to 14.04.  Halfway through the update, it stopped downloading.  After 2 hours, I shut down the computer.  Now when I start, I get a screen indicated:

> System is running in low graphics mode.

If I click OK, I get a dialogue box which I do not know what it is asking for.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Boot into recover mode, and enter the commands

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get --fix-missing
sudo apt-get -f install
```